# Why is libgpiod is corrupting my filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, kernel, gpio, openwrt, libgpiod

I have an OpenWRT system (Intel) where I have to control some GPIOS (it87). I would like to update from the classic sysfs approach (which works fine, but is being deprecated) to the new chardev, using libgpiod.

However, when I use the gpiod-tools (gpioget for instance), after a while using it, random files with random names (but all of them look like output console sentences) starts to create on / directory. Let me show you an example (this is after 1 hour uptime, only blue folders should be there)[image: garbage files]

This happens with OpenWRT 21 & 22, and with kernel 5.4 & 5.10.154.  I really don't know why it is happening.

I tried tweaking some kernel paremeters regarding GPIO, my current cfg is as follows:
[image: kernel CFG]

I tried also enabling both (sysfs & chardev), no luck.

What I'm missing? Could be something in other kernel cfg section?

Thank you! Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: First of all, get rid of pictures in your qustion by replkacing them with plain (maybe formatted) text.

Comment: Second, you didn't show us how you run `gpioget` or any other tools. I 100% believe it's a problem in your scripts and `libgpiod` has nothing to do with that.